# What's wrong with my orderby in Linq to XML select?

Tags: xml, linq, sql-order-by

Using Linq, XML: I loaded the xml file and everything worked until I added the orderby clause. Could you point out my error? Compilation was OK but nothing is shown in the listbox where the results are supposed to be listed. Without the orderby, listbox is populated with entries as expected. Each Name is associated with a unique Code but Code is not part of select new {...}.

```
              var products = from d in xElem.Descendants(fileName)
                    where d.Element(Name) != null
                    orderby d.Element(Code) ascending 
                    select new
                    {
                        ...
                        name = d.Element(Name).Value
                    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Please see my edit with description of problem.

Comment: Do you want "orderby d.Element(Name) ascending"

Comment: No, I want to order by Code which is NOT part of select new {...}. The ascending applies to Code value which is a text field of 8 digits each.

Comment: I figured out what's wrong: I need to have the .Value similar to .Value of Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d.Element(Code)` should be `d.Element(Code).Value`